If-Else statement skips straight to else - I cannot work out why
I am hoping somebody here can run their eyes over the below If - Else statement and shed light on why the If statement seems to be completely skipped and only the 'Else' is actioned.
The application purpose is to query a SQLite3 database to check if a Webhook ID is already processed in the database.
Code successfully retreives the last entered Alert_ID from the database (7960057) and retreives the Webhook_ID from the incoming Webhook (in this instance is: 7960058)
Both AlERT_ID from the database and the Webhook Alert_ID (WHook_Id) print correctly in the terminal.
Below is the print statement out of the terminal, and as can be seen the Webhook Id (7960057) does not equal the Database Last Entry (7960058), however the If statement appears to be ignoring this and returning the action of the 'Else' statement. The Debugger is not showing any errors.
WebHook ID = 7960058
Database Last Entry (DBresult) = 7960057
Alert_Id: 7960058 already exists in Webhook DB; Order NOT Committed

Apologies if the resolution to this is simple - I am working hard to self-learn python and SQLite; so admittedly i am a bit of a noob.
I have googled and read many answers to similar problem - but cannot find any answer that points to why my code is working as it should.
I suspect one of the numbers dont match in terms of type, and the JSON retrieved number may be in the form of a Byte Indice and the database retrieved number of a different type; but i cant find how to check this.
Thankyou for your help on this :-)
WHook_Id = "7960058" #7960058 is entered for sake of example, real code pulls data from a JSON message which = 7960058 : (WHook_Id = message_data['Alert_ID'])
    print("WebHook ID = " + WHook_Id)
    print(type(WHook_Id))

db = get_db()
cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ALERT_ID FROM WebHook_SigDB WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM WebHook_SigDB)")
DBresult = cur.fetchone()
    print(f"Database Last Entry (DBresult) = {DBresult[0]}")
    print(type(DBresult[0]))
    
if DBresult == WHook_Id:
    print("Alert_Id: " + str(WHook_Id) + " already exists in Webhook DB; Order NOT Committed")
else:
    print("Alert ID:" + str(WHook_Id) + "does not exist in WebHook DB; Commit Order")
        for ord in bktOrders:
            ib.placeOrder(FutContract, ord) 


What the hell its indention? It will not work.

Indentation is a critical aspect of Python syntax. Try: Getting started

I agree the indentation above looks problematic. The indentation above has occurred due to trying to paste this code and get to display in a code block in Stackoverflow by inserting 4 spaces before each line - the only way i can get it to work. Other methods in the Stackoverflow guide, such as '''    '''dont work for me. So the indentation of 'if and else' in the actual script in VS code is correct - and i did not see i had placed too many 4xspaces in front of the 'else' statement pasted above. I will try to modify this post to represent correctly.

From what I understand, you wonder about why given ...

Below is the print statement out of the terminal, and as can be seen the Webhook Id (7960057) does not equal the Database Last Entry (7960058), however the If statement appears to be ignoring this and returning the action of the 'Else' statement

..., this code ...
if DBresult == WHook_Id:
    ....
else:
    ....

... jumps to "else" in the case that they are different.
Well, because with DBresult == WHook_Id you check if they're equal, so if they aren't equal, the code below the if will not be executed and thus "jumps" to the else clause.
Any chance you meant to check for their inequality instead? Then you could:
if DBresult != WHook_Id:
    ....

Also make sure you compare the same types. If one is an integer and the other (as it seems in your example) is a string, they will never be equal.

thankyou for the direction you have provided in respect to what to look into to help problem solve - i had ran out of ideas.
your observation of 'check inequality instead' was correct as one of my last problem solve attempts was to swap the if/else outcomes over to see what happened - and i forgot to put them back into original position. Even when i do use != and manually change webhook id to = the last id in the database - the if/else statement still doesnt perform as it should.

example result from terminal:
<class 'int'>
Database Last Entry (DBresult) = 7960057
<class 'int'>
Alert ID:7960057 does not exist in WebHook DB; Commit Order plus i checked the object types of each; which both print out to be Integers and hence the same.

@Trent could you update your original question with the updated code, the expected result and this error message? I assumed the indentation issue was just formatting difficulties with the site here. Still, it makes sense to try and fix that, so others can read it.
